# Model fitting: glm vs glmmPQL

Tags: r, glm, anova

I am fitting a model regarding absence-presence data and I would like to check whether the random factor is significant or not.
To do this, one should compare a glmm with a glm and check with the LR-test which one is most significant, if I understand correct.

But if I perform an ANOVA(glm,glmm) , I get an analysis of Deviance Table and no output that compares the models.

How do I get the output that I desire, thus comparing both models?

Thanks in advance,
Koen

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you got the wrong impression about using `anova()` for this. Below `re` was fit using `glmmPQL()` in MASS package. `fe` was fit using `glm()` from base:

```
> anova(re,fe)
#Error in anova.glmmPQL(re, fe) : 'anova' is not available for PQL fits
```

That message appears to be the sole reason `anova.glmmPQL()` was created.

See this thread for verification and vague explanation:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2002-July/022987.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. If someone else would encounter this problem, I solved using the lme4 package and performing an lmer with my model and compared this to a GLM.
The lmer GLMM does give an AIC and thus can be used for comparing both models through AIC.

Comment: If you believe in AIC and logistic models. Check some book on the subject, or at least http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4997/can-aic-compare-across-different-types-of-model and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3984/understanding-aic-and-schwarz-criterion; or Out Master's Voice at http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/05/04/2608.html

Comment: @user2028748 Good. I noticed in some of the threads that there was concern that the likelihood formulation between `glm()` and `lmer()` might differ. Did you come across this? If so, did you find a resolution?

Comment: @ndoogan Yes, that is true. They do might differ. Nevertheless I have read you can still use it to compare it. Though this AIC comparison is not sufficient for deciding which model is the best, but it is an estimate. I have used the AIC's, the very low value of my random factor in glmm and the barely shifting values of the parameter estimates when comparing glmm with glm as other arguments to remove my random factor from glmm and thus decide glm would be the best model fit for my data.

Answer (score 0):

simply `anova` does not work with `glmmPQL` you need to use `glmer` from lme4 package to be able to use `anova`.